# Dropdown turning into textfield on press

Tags: jquery, laravel

I have a few applications in laravel and jquery mobile.

I want a dropdown list of companies. And a option "add company". 
When the users presses "add company" a textfield will appear so the user can fill in a company him/herself.

Does jquery-mobile have an option like this?

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with? The clicking, removing of dropdown, adding of textbox...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. By combining a click (or change) handler with an append operation you can achieve this.

https://api.jquery.com/click

https://api.jquery.com/change

https://api.jquery.com/append